# How can I get a TABLE to respect the narrower environment in ConTeXt?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, context

The narrower environment in ConTeXt is very useful, but TABLEs misbehave inside of it. I would expect a TABLE in a narrower environment to align with the new margin, but instead, the TABLE is aligned with the global margin.

For example, the code below:

```
\starttext
    Normal text

    \setupnarrower[left=2cm]
    \startnarrower[left]
        Narrower text

        \blank[small]
        \bTABLE
            \bTR \bTC Misbehaving \eTC \bTC Table \eTC \eTR
            \bTR \bTC[nc=2]       :(              \eTC \eTR
        \eTABLE
    \stopnarrower
\stoptext
```

Produces this output:

[image: Misaligned Table]

How can I get the TABLE to align with the "Narrower text" instead of the "Normal text"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TABLE` environment starts a `\vbox`, so if it occurs at the beginning of a sentence, it switches to vertical mode. To prevent that, add a `\dontleavehmode`.

```
\starttext
    Normal text

    \setupnarrower[left=2cm]
    \startnarrower[left]
        Narrower text

        \blank[small]
        \dontleavehmode
        \bTABLE
            \bTR \bTC Misbehaving \eTC \bTC Table \eTC \eTR
            \bTR \bTC[nc=2]       :(              \eTC \eTR
        \eTABLE
    \stopnarrower
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Thanks for also explaining why it behaves the way it does without `\dontleavehmode`.

Answer (score 0):

use \midaligned command in front of Narrower Text and in front of \bTable and compile you will get

[image: contxttbl]

Comment: The "Narrower text" was not intended as a title for the table, but was instead intented to represent a paragraph preceding the table, so `midaligned` is not really appropriate.

Comment: Where is the code for your solution?