# ConTeXt: Getting listofpublications to respect current narrower margins

Tags: context

It seems like placing a bibliography using `\placelistofpublications` does not respect the current margins set by `\startnarrower`. I can't seem to find the appropriate variable to insert into the margins options of the list (`\leftmargindistance` doesn't work) and I can't make heads or tails of the `spac-hor.mkiv` source code. Is there any way to feed the current narrowed margins into `\placelistofpublications`?

```
\startbuffer[ref]
@article{work,
  author = {Last, First},
  title = {Fancy title},
  journal = {Journal},
  year = {2000},
  month = {1},
  volume = {1}
}
\stopbuffer

\usebtxdataset[ref.buffer]
\setupbtxrendering[default][numbering=no]

\startsetups btx:default:list:article
\btxflush{title}...
\stopsetups

\starttext
\definenarrower[test][left=4cm,default=left]
\starttest
Test \cite[work] % Indented 4cm

\setupbtxlist[margin=\leftmargindistance]
\placelistofpublications % Not indented sufficiently...

Test % Indented 4cm
\stoptest
\stoptext
```

This question seems similar to [How can I get a TABLE to respect the narrower environment in ConTeXt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307103/how-can-i-get-a-table-to-respect-the-narrower-environment-in-context), but a naive addition of `\dontleavehmode` before `\placelistofpublications` didn't seem to work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues why your code is not working.

1. `\leftmargindistance` is the wrong dimension. The dimension that stores the current value of "margin" is `\leftskip`. It is named so due to historic reasons (the name comes from Plain TeX).
2. `\placelistofpublications` includes a `\forgetall`, so the value of `\leftskip` is reset to zero. So, you need to tell ConTeXt to use the value of `\leftskip` at the time when `\setupbtxlist` is called, not at the time when the value of `margin` is used inside `\placepublications`. This can be done by adding `\expanded`.

So, the following example works:

```
\startbuffer[ref]
@article{work,
  author = {Last, First},
  title = {Fancy title},
  journal = {Journal},
  year = {2000},
  month = {1},
  volume = {1}
}
\stopbuffer

\usebtxdataset[ref.buffer]
\setupbtxrendering[default][numbering=no]

\startsetups btx:default:list:article
\btxflush{title}...
\stopsetups

\starttext
\definenarrower[test][left=4cm,default=left]

\unprotect
\starttest
Test \cite[work] % Indented 4cm
\expanded{\setupbtxlist[margin=\the\leftskip]}
\placelistofpublications % Not indented sufficiently...

Test % Indented 4cm
\stoptest
\stoptext
```